# make a gameobject move to another gameobject that was selected by mouse click?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im currently making a turn based type of game however im stuck figuring out how to move the player to the position of the enemy that was chosen.

This is the player script with the positions of the enemies.

```
 void Update()
 {
     if ((Input.GetKeyDown("1")) && (BattleFlow.playerTurn == 1)) // attack monster 1
     {
         BattleFlow.currentDamage = 40;
         GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("PlayerMelee");
         GetComponent<Transform>().position = new Vector2(-4.78f, 3.68f);
         StartCoroutine(playerAttack());

     }
     else if ((Input.GetKeyDown("1")) && (BattleFlow.playerTurn == 1)) //  attack monster 2
     {
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("PlayerMelee");
        GetComponent<Transform>().position = new Vector2(-4.45f, 1.77f);
       StartCoroutine(playerAttack2());
    }
 }
```

The player can move to the location of monster 1 however the script for monster 2 doesn't work. The player still goes towards the direction of monster 1 even though I clicked monster 2.

This is the code for the mouse click which I placed on the enemy script.

```
// Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
 void OnMouseDown()
     {
         Debug.Log(gameObject.name);
         BattleFlow.selectedEnemy = gameObject.name;

     }
```

Comment: The else clause is checking for exactly the same key as the if clause. Of Course it will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds interesting. I think you need another condition in the if and else if to check the selected monster name. Something like:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("1") && BattleFlow.playerTurn == 1)
{
    if (BattleFlow.selectedEnemy == "monster1name")  //  attack monster 1
    {
        BattleFlow.currentDamage = 40;
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("PlayerMelee");
        GetComponent<Transform>().position = new Vector2(-4.78f, 3.68f);
        StartCoroutine(playerAttack());
    } 
    else if (BattleFlow.selectedEnemy == "monster2name") //  attack monster 2
    {
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("PlayerMelee");
        GetComponent<Transform>().position = new Vector2(-4.45f, 1.77f);
        StartCoroutine(playerAttack2());
    }
}
```

An additional thing, I don't know but it might help to store the selected gameobject instead of just the name:

```
BattleFlow.selectedEnemy = gameObject;
```

That way you can access not only the name of the selected enemy, but anything including the position. It means you could do something like this to generically handle attacking any enemy and you won't need a separate case for each one, assuming you can convert the gameobject transform position to the right position.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("1") && BattleFlow.playerTurn == 1)
{
    var enemyPosition = = BattleFlow.selectedEnemy.transform.position;
    BattleFlow.currentDamage = 40;
    GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("PlayerMelee");
    GetComponent<Transform>().position = enemyPosition;
    StartCoroutine(playerAttack());
}
```

Comment: I have two types of enemies on a single script. Would storing the selected gameobject still work?

Comment: if you only have 2 it probably doesn't matter, I was thinking if there were 20 or so. You should still be able to do it though as even different types are gameobjects.